# form select field saves label not value

Tags: forms

This is my form "select" field.

```
$form['example'] = array(
'#type'=>'select',
'#title' => 'Example',
'#options' => array('return_value1' => t('Display Value 1'), 'return_value2'   => t('Display Value 2')),
);
```

On submit i get in my form_state['values'].. 'Display Value 1' instead of 'return_value1'.

Does anybody have an idea why?

Comment: what mean really ? in submit exist the sumbited value and it will equal `Display Value 1` !!! it is value of submited item

Comment: it should save value, not label. It is even explained in Form API reference.

Comment: tell me what is 'Display Value 1' ? Is not value?

Comment: You tell me who wants to save the label?

Comment: exchange them !!!